# Visual Studio Team Services - release management - Build (error missing nugget)

Tags: continuous-integration, build-process, azure-devops, release-management, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am new to Visual Studio Team Services and trying to apply release management.
In my scenario,  i have my local machine "A" which has Visual Studio 2015 installed and Connected to VSTS.

I am going to check in code changes from this machine and use it as an agent that will get new releases from release management (installed the agent service on it)

I have created this agent under new pool **MyMachine** and downloaded it to machine A, and the service is running.

[image]

I created the release definition (with 2 environments, no tasks) and bind it to Build definition. The Build definition uses Visual Studio as a template:
[image]

and **MyMachine** as Default agent Queue :

[image]

I commit new changes from Machine A, new builds were add to VSTS but it gives the following error( i change **MyMachine** pool to **Hosted**, the error persists)

[image]

**Questions:**

1. Where is the build happening when i specify the hosted pool and MyMachine pool?
2. What is the cause of the build error and how we fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to restore the nuget packages on the hosted build agent.
You can add a Nuget restore step before Visual Studio step:
[image]